# Overflow from a div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div that the client will be doing some actions that (with JavaScript) will change the content.  Sometimes this content will get annoyingly long.  Is there a "simple" way to do this?  I've messed with the CSS "Overflow" property and it works alright but I'd rather only have a vertical scroll bar, no horizontal scroll bars.

This is also assuming that some of the content doesn't include spaces (which will produce the normal effect).

I need it to split it in the middle of the word if it requires doing so.

Example:

```
I want the overflow to acti
vate even if it is in the m
iddle of a word.
```

Thanks if you can.  Here is a jsFiddle of what I'm *kind of* working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/DalexL/znzk2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
overflow-y: auto
overflow-x: none
```

and also

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thanks so much.  I'll accept this as the answer in 7 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

there's also [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

```
word-break: break-all;
```

current support is limited though, appears to be IE9, Chrome, Safari only, but may be worthwhile for the `hyphenate` option

```
word-break: hyphenate;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting the width of the div? and its overflow to `overflow:auto`
I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you set html and body overflow to hidden, and your div height to 100% with overflow auto, that will not work. The div will keep flowing out of the window as it was told to use 100% height of the body. if you want overflow to work, it needs to have a max-height at some point not exceeding the body height so that nothing gets hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/XvcXC/1

Edit: So i misunderstood your problem as seem like something has changed since i first saw your question. Updated here http://jsfiddle.net/robx/XvcXC/2/ to break long lines of text.

Comment: Have a point my friend :) Sadly, Kasturi beat you, so I can't award you an "accepted answer".

Comment: No problem. But do be aware that the problem is still there should your div element flows beyond your  body height, that overflow for your div using 100% height will be hidden.